# plot time series with constraint

Tags: r

I have a big dataset and I'd like to plot zizi vs hour but only for each hour while the variables looks like this:

```
> datasetjc$hour[1:100]
  [1] 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23
 [40] 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [79]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 

> datasetjc$zizi[1:100]
  [1]  2 27  2  3 45  0  6  0 15  8  3  1  4  0  0 15  1 13  0 15 23  8 21  2  0  9 43 26 31 33 11  0  4  7 26  2 25 14  1
 [40]  3  1  6  3  4  3  2 27  2  3 45  0  7  0 15  8  3  1  4  0  4 26  0 15  1  4  0 15 14 12 23  8  3 21 13  2  0 32 43
 [79] 31 11  4  0  4  7 26 10  2 25 25  1  1  4  4 23  3  2 27  2 45  0
>
```

I also have the minutes, dates and days vaiables. Each data are only separated by 5 minutes. How can I do the plot?

Thx

Comment: What do you mean "but only for each hour"? Do you mean only plot $hour data that are not `0`?  I.e. all the `23`s?

Comment: Looks like you have multiple entries of `zizi` for the same hour -- what do you want to display?  The mean of the `zizi` values for that hour?

Comment: I mean for each day, I want to plot zizi vs hour for hour equal 0, 1, 2, ... 23 while here I have steps of 5 min

Comment: I'm interested to know how to compute the mean of the zizi values for each hour

Answer (score 0):

If we take your question to be "how do I get hourly summaries of data taken at five minute intervals", then this is a classic split-apply-combine.  [Average data by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/averaging-column-values-for-specific-sections-of-data-corresponding-to-other-col/11562850) is a great summary of the different techniques.

For this particular example, in vanilla R you use the `aggregate` or `by` function.

```
> df <- data.frame(hour=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), zizi=1:8)
> aggregate(zizi ~ hour, data=df, mean)
  hour zizi
1    1  1.5
2    2  3.5
3    3  5.5
4    4  7.5
```

If you wish to summarize by date/hour, then you use `+`:

```
> aggregate(zizi ~ hour + day, data=df, mean)
```

For more advanced versions of this, I would recommend investing some time in learning either `dplyr` or `data.table`, as both are excellent libraries for doing more complex versions of this extremely common task.

Also for future reference, see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for suggestions on how to pose a question more clearly.